# Wrong column names in netbeans (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, netbeans, bind

Im trying to bind my database with a JTable, however when I try to netbeans does not give me the right column names to bind with.  As you can see with the print screen, I have columns: id, name, email, registration and tyreColourCode in my table, however netbeans only allows me to select from id, address, email and name.

wrong column names:

[image: showing wrong column names]

what the column names should be:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following:

On the upper left part choose Projects-Source Packages-Your_Package. There you will see that additionally to your jFrame the .java file with description of your database table occurred. Open its Source, find incorrect columns and change them:

```
@Column(name = "your_column_name")
private String variable_name;
```

Hope, it helps.